# Smoothing out ggplot2 map

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, interpolation

## Previous Posts

[Cleaning up a map using geom_tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052725/cleaning-up-a-map-using-geom-tile)

[Get boundaries to come through on states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957378/get-boundaries-to-come-through-on-states)

## Problem/Question

I'm trying to smooth out some data to map with ggplot2.  Thanks to @MrFlick and @hrbrmstr, I've made a lot of progress, but am having problems getting a "gradient" effect over the states I need listed.

Here is an example to give you an idea about what I'm looking for :

**** This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

http://nrelscience.org/2013/05/30/this-is-how-i-did-it-mapping-in-r-with-ggplot2/

(1) How can I make the most of ggplot2 with my data?

(2) Is there a better method for achieving a gradient effect?

## Goals

Goals I would like to achieve from this bounty is :

(1) Interpolate the data to build a raster object and then plot with ggplot2

(or, if more can be done with the current plot and the raster object is not a good strategy)

(2) Build a better map with ggplot2

## Current Results

I've been playing around with a lot of these different plots, but am still not happy with the results for two reasons: (1) The gradient isn't telling as much as I'd like; and (2) The presentation could be improved, although I'm not sure how to do it.

As @hrbrmstr has pointed out, it might provide better results if I did some interpolating with the data to produce more data, and then fit those into a raster object and plot with ggplot2.  I think this is what I should be after at this point, but I'm not sure how to do this given the data I have.

I've listed below the code I have done so far with the results.  I really appreciate any help in this matter.  Thank you.

### Data sets

Here are two data sets :

(1) Full data set (175 mb) : PRISM_1895_db_all.csv (NOT AVAILABLE)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uglvwufcr6e9oo6/PRISM_1895_db_all.csv?dl=0

(2) Partial data set (14 mb) : PRISM_1895_db.csv (NOT AVAILABLE)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0evuvrlm49ab9up/PRISM_1895_db.csv?dl=0

*** EDIT : To those interested, the data sets are not available, but I've made a post on my website that connects this code with a subset of California data at http://johnwoodill.com/pages/r-code.html

### Plot 1

```
PRISM_1895_db <- read.csv("/.../PRISM_1895_db.csv")

regions<- c("north dakota","south dakota","nebraska","kansas","oklahoma","texas","minnesota","iowa","missouri","arkansas", "illinois", "indiana", "wisconsin")

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_point(data = PRISM_1895_db, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = APPT), alpha = .5, size = 5) +
  geom_polygon(data=subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="white", fill=NA) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

### Plot 2

PRISM_1895_db <- read.csv("/.../PRISM_1895_db.csv")

```
regions<- c("north dakota","south dakota","nebraska","kansas","oklahoma","texas","minnesota","iowa","missouri","arkansas", "illinois", "indiana", "wisconsin")

ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data=subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
    geom_point(data = PRISM_1895_db, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = APPT), alpha = .5, size = 5, shape = 15) +
    geom_polygon(data=subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="white", fill=NA) +
    coord_equal()
```

[image]

### Plot 3

```
   PRISM_1895_db <- read.csv("/.../PRISM_1895_db.csv")

    regions<- c("north dakota","south dakota","nebraska","kansas","oklahoma","texas","minnesota","iowa","missouri","arkansas", "illinois", "indiana", "wisconsin")

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  stat_summary2d(data=PRISM_1895_db, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, z = APPT)) +
  geom_polygon(data=subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions), aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="white", fill=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this wonderful question. I  am also quite interested in it but the link to the data is not available. Could you provide a new link? Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://johnwoodill.github.io/code.html

Comment: @YangYang Sorry for the late response and thanks for posting a link to my site. See link for an example using California instead of the described example here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [CRAN spatial view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) got me started on "Kriging". The code below takes ~7 minutes to run on my laptop. You could try simpler interpolations (e.g., some sort of spline). You might also remove some of the locations from the high-density regions. You don't need all of those spots to get the same heatmap. As far as I know, there is no easy way to create a true gradient with `ggplot2` (`gridSVG` has a few options but nothing like the "grid gradient" you would find in a fancy SVG editor).

[image]

As requested, here is interpolation using splines (much faster). Alot of the code is taken from [Plotting contours on an irregular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339296/plotting-contours-on-an-irregular-grid?lq=1).

[image]

Code for kriging:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(automap)

# Data munging
states=c("AR","IL","MO")
regions=c("arkansas","illinois","missouri")
PRISM_1895_db = as.data.frame(fread("./Downloads/PRISM_1895_db.csv"))
sub_data = PRISM_1895_db[PRISM_1895_db$state %in% states,c("latitude","longitude","APPT")]
coord_vars = c("latitude","longitude")
data_vars = setdiff(colnames(sub_data), coord_vars)
sp_points = SpatialPoints(sub_data[,coord_vars])
sp_df = SpatialPointsDataFrame(sp_points, sub_data[,data_vars,drop=FALSE])

# Create a fine grid
pixels_per_side = 200
bottom.left = apply(sp_points@coords,2,min)
top.right = apply(sp_points@coords,2,max)
margin = abs((top.right-bottom.left))/10
bottom.left = bottom.left-margin
top.right = top.right+margin
pixel.size = abs(top.right-bottom.left)/pixels_per_side
g = GridTopology(cellcentre.offset=bottom.left,
             cellsize=pixel.size,
             cells.dim=c(pixels_per_side,pixels_per_side))

# Clip the grid to the state regions
map_base_data = subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions)
colnames(map_base_data)[match(c("long","lat"),colnames(map_base_data))] = c("longitude","latitude")
foo = function(x) {
  state = unique(x$region)
  print(state)
  Polygons(list(Polygon(x[,c("latitude","longitude")])),ID=state)
}
state_pg = SpatialPolygons(dlply(map_base_data, .(region), foo))
grid_points = SpatialPoints(g)
in_points = !is.na(over(grid_points,state_pg))
fit_points = SpatialPoints(as.data.frame(grid_points)[in_points,])

# Do kriging
krig = autoKrige(APPT~1, sp_df, new_data=fit_points)
interp_data = as.data.frame(krig$krige_output)
colnames(interp_data) = c("latitude","longitude","APPT_pred","APPT_var","APPT_stdev")

# Set up map plot
map_base_aesthetics = aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, group=group)
map_base = geom_polygon(data=map_base_data, map_base_aesthetics)
borders = geom_polygon(data=map_base_data, map_base_aesthetics, color="black", fill=NA)

nbin=20
ggplot(data=interp_data, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=APPT_pred),color=NA) +
  stat_contour(aes(z=APPT_pred), bins=nbin, color="#999999") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue",mid="white",high="red", midpoint=mean(interp_data$APPT_pred)) +
  borders +
  coord_equal() +
  geom_point(data=sub_data,color="black",size=0.3)
```

Code for spline interpolation:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(automap)
library(plyr)
library(akima)

# Data munging
sub_data = as.data.frame(fread("./Downloads/PRISM_1895_db_all.csv"))
coord_vars = c("latitude","longitude")
data_vars = setdiff(colnames(sub_data), coord_vars)
sp_points = SpatialPoints(sub_data[,coord_vars])
sp_df = SpatialPointsDataFrame(sp_points, sub_data[,data_vars,drop=FALSE])

# Clip the grid to the state regions
regions<- c("north dakota","south dakota","nebraska","kansas","oklahoma","texas",
            "minnesota","iowa","missouri","arkansas", "illinois", "indiana", "wisconsin")
map_base_data = subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions)
colnames(map_base_data)[match(c("long","lat"),colnames(map_base_data))] = c("longitude","latitude")
foo = function(x) {
  state = unique(x$region)
  print(state)
  Polygons(list(Polygon(x[,c("latitude","longitude")])),ID=state)
}
state_pg = SpatialPolygons(dlply(map_base_data, .(region), foo))

# Set up map plot
map_base_aesthetics = aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, group=group)
map_base = geom_polygon(data=map_base_data, map_base_aesthetics)
borders = geom_polygon(data=map_base_data, map_base_aesthetics, color="black", fill=NA)

# Do spline interpolation with the akima package
fld = with(sub_data, interp(x = longitude, y = latitude, z = APPT, duplicate="median",
                            xo=seq(min(map_base_data$longitude), max(map_base_data$longitude), length = 100),
                            yo=seq(min(map_base_data$latitude), max(map_base_data$latitude), length = 100),
                            extrap=TRUE, linear=FALSE))
melt_x = rep(fld$x, times=length(fld$y))
melt_y = rep(fld$y, each=length(fld$x))
melt_z = as.vector(fld$z)
level_data = data.frame(longitude=melt_x, latitude=melt_y, APPT=melt_z)
interp_data = na.omit(level_data)
grid_points = SpatialPoints(interp_data[,2:1])
in_points = !is.na(over(grid_points,state_pg))
inside_points = interp_data[in_points, ]

ggplot(data=inside_points, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=APPT)) + 
  stat_contour(aes(z=APPT)) +
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue",mid="white",high="red", midpoint=mean(inside_points$APPT)) +
  borders
```

Comment: This is a great answer and is exactly what I'm looking for.  However, since i need a larger region that includes more states, this is going to take a while to run and I have 75 years I need to plot.  Could you help with applying a spline so it will run a bit faster?

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  Great answer!  Can you please explain the `xo=seq(1.02*min(longitude), max(longitude), length = 400),
                            yo=seq(0.96*min(latitude), max(latitude), length = 400),`  I'm not entirely sure why 1.02 and 0.96....thanks

Comment: That was an ugly hack. Confusing I know. I wanted the grid used for interpolation to encompass all of the states. The problem was that `min(latitude)` was just north of the southern tip of Texas, so I multiplied it by 0.96 to extend the grid south a bit. I realize now it's better to do `xo=seq(min(map_base_data$longitude), max(map_base_data$longitude), length = 100)`. I've changed the code in my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ok great that works.  Is there a reason why you scaled down the length to 100?  The only other thing I'm not sure about is the `rep(x, times)` and `rep(x, each)`.  I understand it replicates the data in `fld$x` or `fld$y`, but why use times and each?  I've finally finished reviewing the code and it's great.  Just unsure on this last part.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's hard to explain what `rep(x,times)` and `rep(x,each)` do without seeing it. Read the help file; make a small matrix; and play around with it. That's what I did. I scaled down the length to because it's faster that way, although the results image will have less resolution (100x100 instead of 400x400 tiles). You can tune the grid size to your preferences.

Comment: Ok great.  I was reading through the help file, but it's not as explicit as I'd hope.  I'll take your suggestions and play around with a small matrix.  Thanks again for a great answer!

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the point of `rep()` with `times` and `each` is to create additional long/lat (times each latitude, for each longitude) against the interpolated values of z, and then match them into a data frame, thus creating a large matrix of replicated values?  This seems like an essential step in interpolating spatial data since `interp()` only creates values for z.  Am I saying this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer was prbly not optimal (or accurate) for your needs. This is a bit of a hack:

```
gg <- ggplot() 
gg <- gg + geom_polygon(data=subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions), 
                        aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=PRISM_1895_db, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, color=APPT), 
                      size=5, alpha=1/15, shape=19)
gg <- gg + scale_color_gradient(low="#023858", high="#ece7f2")
gg <- gg + geom_polygon(data=subset(map_data("state"), region %in% regions), 
                        aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="white", fill=NA)
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg
```

that requires changing `size` in `geom_point` for larger plots, but you get a better gradient effect than the `stat_summary2d` behavior and it's conveying the same information.

[image]

Another option would be to interpolate more `APPT` values between the longitude & latitudes you have, then convert that to a more dense raster object and plot it with `geom_raster` like in the example you provided.

Comment: hmmmm....this is kind of hard to see the differences....is there a parameter that would help clean this up?  Thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This seems to be a bit better than what I've done so far so I'll play around with this.  I think you are right about interpolating some additional values, but I'm building this as a function so I can run multiple plots of about 80 years so it might be a bit difficult from that regard.  This is preliminary research and I just need some nice plots for my advisor and a presentation to get the idea across.  Eventually I'll be modelling this data to fit a trig function to get daily averages and then your raster idea will be perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: You think you can help me further with this?  I'm not getting any further attention on the bounty and would really appreciate the help.  In particular, I think you're right with interpolating the values to increase the points on the graph.   But I'm not exactly sure about how to apply them to a raster object, or even create the additional points.